# Prevent Serialization of Created ActionResult

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

Say I have an async web api 2 controller method returning a Created ActionResult like:

```
return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + Item.Id), Item);
```

`Item` has a property `ItemDescriptions` which I would like to truncate on response. How do I define serialization for a Created Web Api response like this?

I tried creating a custom resolver like:

```
public class ItemContractResolver: CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.PropertyName == "ItemDescriptions")
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = i => false;
            property.ShouldDeserialize = i => false;
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Which I later set in the Controller constructor like:

```
        var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new ItemContractResolver();
```

But that sadly does not work and the `ItemDescriptions` property is still serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JsonProperty.PropertyName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_PropertyName.htm) is the **serialized** name of the property.  Since you are inheriting from `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` it will be `"itemDescriptions"`.

Instead, check against [`JsonProperty.UnderlyingName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_UnderlyingName.htm) which is the *name of the underlying member or parameter*:

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

    if (typeof(Item).IsAssignableFrom(property.DeclaringType) 
        && property.UnderlyingName == nameof(Item.ItemDescriptions))
    {
        property.Ignored = true;
    }

    return property;
}
```

Notes -

- Setting [`JsonProperty.Ignored`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Ignored.htm) should be simpler and slightly more performant than setting `ShouldSerialize` and `ShouldDeserialize` delegates.
- Using [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) avoids hardcoding the property name.
- It seems wise to check that the type being serialized inherits from `Item` in case a property named `ItemDescriptions` is later added to some unrelated type.
- You could always just mark the property with [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) - unless the type is in some external library and cannot be modified.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SJrOg6).

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I have been looking for.